# Spring Boot JPA @UpdateTimestamp not working with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm facing strange issue last modified date is not getting updated automatically.
I'm using **Postgresql Version 12.3** and **Springboot 2.2.4.RELEASE**
Here's my Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
)
@Data
public class Users {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
        private String userId;

        private String userName;

        private String userEmail;

        private String userPhoneNumber;

        @CreationTimestamp
        @Column(updatable = false)
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "GMT+05:30")
        private Timestamp createdOn;

        @UpdateTimestamp
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "GMT+05:30")
        private Timestamp lastUpdatedOn;

}
```

Database Records:

```
            createdon        |      lastupdatedon
 2020-08-27 07:43:37.994 | 2020-08-27 07:43:37.994
 2020-08-07 07:49:22.797 | 2020-08-07 07:49:22.797
 2020-08-12 13:38:43.503 | 2020-08-12 13:38:43.503
```

You can see both createdOn and lastUpdatedOn are same. Even though the records updated frequently last modified date is not getting updated.

I'm saving record with jpa repository
ex:

```
 usersRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: And **how** are you updating those records.

Comment: using jpa methods like,

usersRepository.save(user);

Comment: One thing have you tried without the hibernate specific `dynamicUpdate`? Just wondering. Also are you not updating something with a query somewhere (as that bypasses the listeners).

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried updating the record directly with CLI (psql), even from theer also lastUpdatedOn not changing.

Comment: Ofcourse it won't change if you directly execute SQL. It is a feature of Spring Data JPA, so if you bypass that, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using PrePersist & PreUpdate annotation instead of CreationTimestamp & UpdateTimestampas to have more control on the entity and apply below-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
)
@Data
public class Users {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    private String userName;

    private String userEmail;

    private String userPhoneNumber;

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Timestamp createdOn;

    @Column
    private Timestamp lastUpdatedOn;

    @PrePersist
    public void onInsert() {
      createdOn = Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toInstant());
      lastUpdatedOn = createdOn;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void onUpdate() {
      lastUpdatedOn = Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toInstant());
     }
}
```

Comment: Under the hood, this is what eventually will be used, although through a listener.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the save method within a transaction, by chance?

The timestamps are populated when written to the DB, so you won't see their values until *after* the transaction has been committed.

When I ran into this issue, I had code that looked like this:

```java
@Transactional
public Response createFooBusinessLogic(Foo foo) {
    var createdEntity = fooRepository.save(foo);
    return someMethodUsingCreatedTime(createdEntity);
}
```

There are two solutions:

1. If the dates are required by another entity in the DB transaction, you can use `saveAndFlush` instead of `save`. This forces a write to the DB, returning back your created and modified dates.
2. Otherwise, refactor the `save` call into another method and annotate that method with `@Transactional`.

I went with option (2), which looked like this:

```java
public Response createFooBusinessLogic(Foo foo) {
    var createdEntity = facade.saveFoo(foo);
    return someMethodUsingCreatedTime(createdEntity);
}

// In Facade.java
@Transactional
public Foo saveFoo(Foo foo) {
    return fooRepository.save(foo);
}
```

Note that for the transaction annotation to work, the call must not be self-invoking (ie. must be called on another class) and the method must be public.